# Form validation causing wrong input in database from form field

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using a javascript that validates a form by radio buttons being checked, depending on which button is checked I want a value for that button submitted to MySQL but when I select a button it submits the button name to MySQL. changing the name of the button causes the script to stop working. How can I change the script so it allows the button value to post to MySQL instead of the button name?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma376/1/)

```
function ValidateForm(form) {
ErrorText = "";
if ((form.job_status[0].checked === false) && (form.job_status[1].checked === false)) {
    alert("Before you can get a signature you must mark a selection.\n Is the work completed or do you need to return?");
    return false;
}
if (ErrorText = "") {
    form.submit();
}
```

}

Comment: This code has nothing to do with what's sent to MySQL. Please show us the PHP code where you write your queries.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha this code has everything to do with what is sent to MySQL. because until I started using it the button values would post to MySQL now that I require the buttons be validated it sends the name of the button not the value of the button.

Answer (score 0):

`job_status[0] ,job_status[1]` means with name `job_status` two radio buttons exist.

If you change one of the radio buttons name either of `job_status[0]` `job_status[1]`  one will exist.So you are getting exception

Instead of doing all that process by default select a radio button.That solves all your problems.I updated the link

[**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma376/7/)

Comment: That wont work for me because it removes the validation by having a box checked by default allows the form to be submitted with out the user actually having to check the box themselves.